# What are the total number of diagonals in a tesseract (four-dimensional cube) including body and face diagonals?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

- What is the total number of diagonals in a tesseract, including both body diagonals (diameter) and face diagonals?

For context:

I was working on a small project using TypeScript React framework, it consists in a "Multidimensional Tic-Tac-Toe" (sounds crazy I know). But the main idea is build a Tic-Tac-Toe where I can chose the size of my board (like instead of a traditional 3x3 a 4x4 or bigger) and also in how many dimensions I want to play. (like in a 3x3x3 cube, maybe a bigger cube or in a 3x3x3x3 Tesseract). I'm working with the linearization of matrix in a one dimensional array, so I know that the size of my game array is:

$$s = size^{dimension}$$

The next thing is to modelate how many ways there is to win considering the size and the number of dimensions. So considering that diagonals is a way to win the game I was wondering:

- a square has 2 diagonals
- a cube has 4 body diagonals and 12 face diagonals, resulting in a total of 16 diagonals.

I am interested in understanding the number of diagonals in a tesseract, as well as whether there are any new types of diagonals that arise in the four-dimensional context, similar to the emergence of face diagonals in three-dimensional cubes. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: any two vertices define either an edge or a diagonal. So you just need to know the number of vertices and the number of edges.

Answer (score 2):

Pick some $n\geq1$ and put your $n$-dimensional hypercube into an $n$-dimensional coordinate system, such that each vertex has coordinates that have only $0$ and $1$ as entries. This will make it very easy to classify and count the different diagonals later.

There are $2^n$ vertices. Any pair of vertices (there are $\binom{2^n}2=2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ such pairs) define a distinct line segment. Such a segment is either an edge in the cube or it is a diagonal of some kind.

Each vertex is connected to $n$ edges. And each edge is connected to $2$ vertices. So there are $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ edges. Thus the remaining $2^{n-1}(2^n-n-1)$ segments must be diagonals. To classify all these segments into edges and different types of diagonals, we can consider how many coordinate entries change between its two end points.

For the cube we have $28$ segments. $12$ of them are edges where only a single coordinate entry changes. For instance between the following pairs of points:
$$
(0,0,0)\leftrightarrow (0,1,0)\\
(1,1,0)\leftrightarrow (1,0,0)\\
(1,0,1)\leftrightarrow (1,1,1)
$$
Next, we have the face diagonals, where two coordinate entries change from one end point to the other. There are $12$ of these too, for instance
$$
(0,0,0)\leftrightarrow (1,0,1)\\
(1,0,0)\leftrightarrow (1,1,1)\\
(0,1,0)\leftrightarrow (0,0,1)
$$
Finally, there are the four body diagonals. These are the ones where all coordinate entries change between the two end points. I think you can list them yourself if you do desire.

In general, for an $n$-dimensional cube, and a diagonal type that changes $k$ coordinate entries (including edges, with $k=1$), for each vertex there are $\binom{n}{k}$ such segments with that vertex as an end point, and each segment has two end points. So the total number of such diagonals is $2^{n-1}\cdot\binom nk$.

In the case of your $n=4$ tesseract, there are

- $2^3\cdot\binom 41=32$ edges
- $2^3\cdot\binom 42=48$ face diagonals
- $2^3\cdot\binom 43=32$ facet diagonals (body diagonals of one of the eight cube facets of the tesseract)
- $2^3\cdot\binom 44=8$ full body diagonals

Certainly, each time you go up one dimension, one new type of diagonal appears: The kind that changes all the coordinate entries.