# Enumeration of all the possible rectangles formed by $4$ vertices of a hypercube

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

This question is related to these questions: [Q1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4843357/573047) and [Q2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4695646/573047).

I would like to write a program to enumerate all the rectangles formed by $4$ vertices of an $n$-dimensional hypercube with coordinates in $\{0,1\}^n$, not only the faces of the hypercube, but all the possible rectangles. For example for $n=3$ a valid rectangle which is not a face of the cube is formed by the vertices $(0,0,0)$, $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,1)$, $(1,1,1)$. However, I have difficulties in figuring out what happens with $n > 4$. For example a comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462701/136218) says that $(0,0,1,1)$, $(1,1,0,0)$, $(1,0,1,0)$, $(0,1,0,1)$ is a rectangle, which is not immediate for me.

Any help?

Comment: A quadrilater is a rectangle if it has two pair of parallel sides and a pair of perpendicular sides i.e. given $4$ points on the hypercube $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ we need

$$
P_1-P_2= \pm (P_3-P_4)
$$
$$
P_1-P_3 = \pm (P_2-P_4)
$$
$$
(P_1-P_2) \cdot (P_1 -P_3)=0
$$
The set of vertex of an hypercube is
$$
\{(x_1, \cdots, x_n) : x_i \in \{0,1\}\}
$$ If the dimension is not very high you can check these conditions with a program for all the $2^n$ points
I don't understand to how the et of point you have written is a rectangle. It looks to me is a parallelogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each rectangle can be written as $P$, $P+x$, $P+x+y$, $P+y$. For it to be a rectangle, it suffices that $x\cdot y=0$. Since the hypercube only allows a difference of magnitude $1$ in each coordinate, $x$ and $y$ cannot both be $1$ or both be $-1$ in the same coordinate. Thus, there are no positive contributions to the dot product. Since the dot product is zero, it follows that there are also no negative contributions. So $x$ and $y$ have disjoint support, and if they do, they are necessarily orthogonal.

As for $P$, outside the supports of $x$ and $y$ it can take both values, whereas inside it can only take one of the values ($0$ if $x$ or $y$ has a $1$ and $1$ if $x$ or $y$ has a $-1$).

So for each non-zero vector $x\in\{-1,0,1\}^n$ you can enumerate all non-zero $y\in\{-1,0,1\}^n$ with disjoint support from $x$ and then enumerate all admissible $P$.

This would generate each rectangle four times. You can avoid that by requiring the first non-zero value in both $x$ and $y$ to be $+1$.

Your example $(0,0,1,1), (1,1,0,0), (1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1)$ is a rectangle with $P=(0,0,1,1)$, $x=(1,0,0,-1)$ and $y=(0,1,-1,0)$; it’s a bit confusing because the vertices aren’t specified in order along the perimeter.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a slight minor remark: the rectangles are generated eight times and not four times I think, because we don't have only the sign of $x$ and $y$ but also we can exchange $x$ and $y$. Therefore in addition to what you suggest about requiring that the first non-zero value in both $x$ and $y$ to be $+1$ we should choose e.g. $x \lt y$.

Comment: @FabiusWiesner: I see. I had somehow wrongly convinced myself that $x$ and $y$ couldn't be swapped :-) I realize now that that merely changes the orientation of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

As pointed out in the comments the formula that i have written is not correct. As this answer is off topic I have asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851737/recurrence-realtion-for-the-number-of-rectangle-in-a-d-dimensional-cube) to undestand why. I will not delete this answer as there are comments into it

Let start by proving some preliminary results:

Let $C$ a $d$-dimensional cube and let call $F_k$, for $1 \le k < d$ a $k$-dimensional face of the cube

---

**lemma 1** if $\ell$ is a line segment of $C$ such that $\ell \not \subset F_{d-1}$ for all the $d-1$-dimensional faces then there isn't any line parallel and distinct to $\ell$

---

If a line is not contained in any $d-1$ dimensional face of the cube then it has to be a $d$-diagonal (or main diagonal) of $C$. As all the main diagonals of an hypercube passes throught the center of the hypercube they intersect with each other. So if a line parallel and distinct to $\ell$ it has to be contained in a $d-1$ dimensional face $F_{d-1}$.

So let's consider $\ell' \subset F_{d-1}$ By rotating the cube we can suppose $F_{d-1} \subset \{ (x_1,\cdots, x_d) : x_d=0 \}$. So in particular the direction of $\ell'$  is $(x_1, \cdots, x_{d-1},0)$ for some $x_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$.

As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683930/what-are-the-total-number-of-diagonals-in-a-tesseract-four-dimensional-cube-in) the main diagonals of an hypercube are the line segment whose enpoints have all the coordinates entries distinct. This imply that the direction of a main diagonals is $(x_1, \cdots, x_d)$ such that $x_i= \pm 1$. In particular, $x_d \ne 0$ and so the direction of $\ell$ is not proportional to the direction of $\ell'$ i.e. the two lines are not parallel

---

**lemma 2** if $\ell$ is a $d-1$ diagonal (i.e. $\ell \subset F_{d-1}$, but $\ell \not \subset F_{d-2}$ for any $d-2$ dimensional face) than there exists only 1 line segment $\ell'$ that is parallel and distinct to $\ell$. We have $\ell' \subset F'_{d-1}$ where $F'_{d-1}$ is the $d-1$ dimensional face parallel to $F_{d-1}$

---

By rotating the cube we can suppose $F_{d-1} \subset \{x_d=0\}$. $\ell$ is a main diagonal of $F_{d-1}$. By lemma 1 applied to $F_{d-1}$ there are segment lines in $F_{d-1}$ that are parallel and distinct to $\ell$.

Let call $P_1:=(x_1, \cdots x_{d-1},0)$ and $P_2=(y_1, \cdots, y_{d-1},0)$ the endpoints of $\ell$. As in the proof of lemma 1 we have $x_i-y_1 \ne 0$ for each $i$.

Let call $F_{d-1}' \subset {x_d=1}$ $d-1$ face parallel to $F_{d-1}$. We have $P'_1=P_1+(0, \cdots , 0,1) \in  F_{d-1}'$ and $P'_2=P_2+(0, \cdots , 0,1) \in  F_{d-1}'$. The segment line $\ell'$ with direction $P'_1-P'_2$ is parallel to $\ell$ and is a $d-1$ diagonal

If we have another segment line $\ell'' \subset F'_{d-1}$ parallel to $\ell$, by the transitivity of the parallelism we will have a segment line parallel and distinct to one of the main diagonal of $F'_{d-1}$, but this is impossible for lemma 1

Suppose there exists $\ell'' \parallel \ell$ not contained in $F_{d-1}$ nor $F'_{d-1}$ than by lemma 1 it can't be a main diagonal of $C$. So it has to change at least one of the coordinates entries of its endpoints. This can't be the last, so at least one of the first $d-1$ coordinates entries of the direction of $\ell''$ is $0$. That means that $\ell'' \not \parallel \ell$

---

**lemma 3** Let $R$ a rectangle whose vertex are vertex of $C$ if $R \not \subset F_{d-1}$ for any $d-1$ face than two of the sides of $R$ are parallel $d-1$ diagonals. Conversely the enpoints of a pair of $d-1$ diagonal forms a rectangle that is not contained in any $d-1$ face

---

If two sides of $R$ are in the same $F_{d-1}$ face than all the vertex are in such face. i.e. the rectangle is contained $F_{d-1}$ so the sides have to be in four different $d-1$ faces.

If two segment lines are contained in not parallel $d-1$ faces they are not parallel (as their directions have zeros in different coordinate entries). So the $4$ sides of the rectangle has to be in two pairs of parallel $d-1$ faces. W.l.o.g. I will assume that they are the one contained in $\{x_d=0\}$,$\{x_d=1\}$,$\{x_{d-1}=0\}$,$\{x_{d-1}=1\}$

Let now $P_1=(x_1, \cdots x_{d-2},0,0)$, $P_2=(y_1, \cdots, y_{d-2},0,1)$, $P_3=(z_1, \cdots, z_{d-2},1,0)$, $P_4=(w_1, \cdots w_{d-2},1,1)$ the vertices of $R$ with $P_1-P_2 \parallel P_3-P_4$ and $P_1-P_3 \parallel P_2-P_4$. *i.e.* $x_i-y_i= \pm z_i -w_i$ and $x_i-z_i = \pm y_i- w_i$. As the segments line are not in the same $n-1$ face we also have, for each $i$ that $x_i, y_i,z_i,w_i$ are not all equal.

It is easy to see that this two conditions are equivalent to $x_i=y_i \ne z_i =w_i$ or $x_i=w_i \ne y_i = z_i$

the proof of lemma 3 becames equivalent to:

*Let $d \ge 3$ and $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ boolean vectors as above, than either $P_1-P_2$ and $P_3-P_4$ or $P_1-P_3$ and $P_3-P_4$ have $d-1$ not zero entries*

that can be proven by an easy induction argument (that I omitt for the sake of brevity)

Let now $\ell_1$,$\ell_2$ two $(d-1)$ diagonals, by lemma 2 they lie in two parallel $n-1$ faces. Assume they are $\{x_d=0\}$, $\{x_d=1\}$. Than the other $d-1$ coordinates of the endpoints of $\ell_{1,2}$ are distinct. i.e. the rectangle having these $4$ endpoints as vertices does not lie in any $n-1$ dimensional face

---

**Main result** : Let $r_d$ the number of rectangles with vertex the vertex of a $d$-dimensional cube, than
$$
r_d=2d r_{d-1} + 2^{d-2} d 
$$

---

As shown in the linked answer there are $2^{d-1}d$ $d-1$ diagonals of $C$ i.e. $2^{d-2}d$ pair of parallel $d-1$ diagonals.

By lemma 3  $R$ is a rectangle not contained in an $n-1$ dimensional face iif two of its sides are parallel $d-1$ diagonals. So there are $ 2^{d-2} d $ rectangles that are not contained in any $d-1$ face of $C$.
There are $2d$ distinct $d-1$ dimensional faces, and in any of this face there are $r_{d-1}$ rectangles by definition. So there are $2d r_{d-1}$ rectangles contained in some $n-1$ face.

Comment: Thank you for the work. Although the question is about enumeration of all rectangles, not just counting. Anyway there should be something to be fixed in your count because applying the accepted answer I could find [OEIS A016283](https://oeis.org/A016283), which is $1,12,100,720$.

Comment: @FabiusWiesner: I had actually wondered whether you meant "produce" or "count", as "enumerate" can mean both. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumeration): "In some contexts, such as enumerative combinatorics, the term enumeration is used more in the sense of counting – with emphasis on determination of the number of elements that a set contains, rather than the production of an explicit listing of those elements."

Comment: @joriki nice to know. My knowledge of English and math is limited. Anyway counting the rectangles is interesting too!

Comment: @FabiusWiesner thank you for the feedback. I actually confused enumerate with count. You are correct. The formula i gave has a mistake in it. Indeed i have not subtracted the rectangles that lies in the intersection of more than $1$ $d-1$ face. I have asked a question regarding this